# Category Url Not Found in Multi store

Tags: magento2, category, multistore

I have created a Multi-store and Multi store views i.e 1 is the Default store view 2 is UAE when I click on the category from the default store category shows but when I switch store for default to UAE and click on category it gives me a 404 not found. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog => Categories on admin.

On the top left corner change Scope View to your second store and check if the category is enabled.

If so run the following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This should solve your issue, let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: category is enabled but my url change when i change store like abc.com/uae

Comment: category is showing now but url look like this in uae store uae/catalog/category/view/s/my-category/id/16/

Comment: this is the normal beahviour :)

Comment: we cant make url like shop/for-boys.html

Comment: To the best of my knowledge no. IT has always the store code attached.
Something like
www.mydomain.com/store/storeview

Comment: issue fixed but 1 new thing i want to i want to disable porduct for uae store and enable for other